# Input field loses focus if I don't hold down left-mouse click

Tags: javascript, forms, input

This is 100% of the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="spanName">Hi</span>
</body>
</html>

const mySpan = document.getElementById('spanName');

mySpan.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    document.getElementById('spanName').innerHTML = "<form><input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"enter name\"></input></form>"
})
```

This essentially does what I want it to. When I click on this span, it replaces the inner HTML with the input form. The only problem is that it doesn't stay in focus unless you hold down the left mouse-key. There's nothing else using hover or focus or anything that would compete with the focus.

My best guess is it has something to do with the fact that I'm using the "on-click" event listener, and that's the thing competing with the focus, but clearly the form doesn't just disappear when I unclick the mouse, so the behavior is a little confusing for me.

Heads up, I'm quite new to JavaScript and based off the behavior, I assume that this isn't the correct way to go about this. I had started writing out a bunch of CSS (which I'm also new to), and I currently have a basic navbar at the top full of anchor tags that highlight when I hover over them, but I'm trying to add this into the navbar as a span so that it says "Login" and then when the user clicks on it, the span changes into a login/password form without affecting the other components of the navbar.

That said, aesthetically everything appears to working the way I intended to except for this focus issue. Since it's a problem in this minimal example, I'm assuming it's an issue independent of the other code I've written

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A side note: I would usually create a `form` element via `document.createElement` and add all of the contents inside it instead of using `innerHTML`.  It gives you more control over the elements and makes it a bit more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Just define an Id to your input and after call the focus function.

```js
const mySpan = document.getElementById('spanName');

mySpan.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    document.getElementById('spanName').innerHTML = "<form><input type=\"text\" id=\"myInput\" placeholder=\"enter name\"></input></form>";

    document.querySelector("#myInput").focus();
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="spanName">Hi</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.focus()` on the input element will help, as @Vinicius has demonstrated in his answer.

I modified your HTML a bit in that I replaced your `<span>` with a `<form>` element. In order to make it behave like a span I added some `display:inline-block` style to it. I also added an `.onsubmit` handler that will process the input value after you press return.

```js
document.getElementById('frmName').onclick = e =>{
  const frm=e.target
  frm.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"enter name\">";
  const inp=frm.children[0];
  frm.onsubmit=ev=>(console.log("you entered:",inp.value),false)
  inp.focus();
}
```

```css
form {display:inline-block; cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
abc<form id="frmName">Hi, click me!</form>def
</body>
</html>
```